# javascript force developer to instantiate with the new keyword

Tags: javascript, function

Is there any way in Javascript to force the developer to use the `new` keyword to create a new object?

I know that javascript creates a new object everytime I do this:

```
var module=function(){}
var module = new module();
```

Comment: which developer?! You? Sure you can, just type new

Comment: `var new module = module();` is not valid JavaScript code.

Comment: Sorry, I copied the wrong thing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can check the current `this` object is an instance of the current constructor function, like this

```
function Person(name) {
    if (!(this instanceof Person)) {
        return new Person(name);
    }
    this.name = name;
}
```

You can then check if the object created without `new` is of type `Person` or not, like this

```
console.log(Person("thefourtheye") instanceof Person);
# true
```

Or, if you want the developer to explicitly use `new`, then you can throw an error, as Quentin suggested, like this

```
function Person(name) {
    if (!(this instanceof Person)) {
        throw new Error("Person should be created with `new`")
    }
    this.name = name;
}

Person("thefourtheye");
```

will give

```
/home/thefourtheye/Desktop/Test.js:3
        throw new Error("Person should be created with `new`")
              ^
Error: Person should be created with `new`
    at Person (/home/thefourtheye/Desktop/Test.js:3:15)
```

Comment: Or if you want to force them to use `new` instead of doing for them, `throw` an exception inside the `if`.

Answer (score 2):

In **ECMAScript 6**, you can check the usage of the `new` keyword thanks to `new.target`. Is supported by all browsers, except IE.

> The `new.target` property lets you detect whether a function or constructor was called using the new operator. **In constructors and functions instantiated with the new operator, new.target returns a reference to the constructor or function. In normal function calls, new.target is undefined**.

[Developer Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target)

Take a look at the following example :

```js
function myconstructor() {
    if (!new.target) throw new Error('Constructor must be called using "new" keyword');
    return this;
}

let a = new myconstructor(); // OK
let b = myconstructor(); // ERROR
```